# Error 91 (Object variable or with block variable not set) after using find

Tags: excel, vba

I have some code in VBA worked properly before closing workbook but when I opened that workbook next day showing

> error 91: object variable or with block variable not set

I can't understand what happened.

[image]

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
Dim hq As String, asheet As Worksheet, acell As Range
Dim lrow As Double, test As String
Set asheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
hq = ComboBox1.Value
Debug.Print hq
Set acell = asheet.Range("$Y$1:$EZ$95").Find(what:=hq, LookIn:=xlValues,     lookat:=xlPart, searchorder:=xlByRows, searchdirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False, searchformat:=False)
Debug.Print acell.Column
asheet.Activate
Cells(1, acell.Column).Select
Selection.End(xlDown).Select
lrow = Selection.Row + 1
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(2).Activate

End Sub
```

Comment: Please don't post a tiny screenshot, post your actual code here clearly indicating the error line.

Comment: can you post a link to a sample xlsm file ?

Comment: @patel there is no option to upload files here on Stack Overflow because we won't accept files. The code (or a [mcve]) has to be in the question itself formatted as code  block (Ctrl + K)

Comment: @Peh, I know, but I asked for a link, external link, no upload here

Comment: @patel Note that external links might disappear after a while, and the question becomes useless. According to [ask] the code has to be in the question. • Also we won't trust a file from a unknown source that can execute code ;)

Answer (score 0):

The error message

> error 91: object variable or with block variable not set

means that the variable `acell` is `Nothing` because the `find()` method found nothing! After using `find` you will need to check if it was successful:

```
If Not acell Is Nothing Then
    'something was found
    Debug.Print acell.Column
Else
    'nothing was found
    Debug.Print "find returned nothing"
End If
```

---

To further investigate your issue [Debug](https://www.excel-easy.com/vba/examples/debugging.html) your code and check the values of your variables. Eg of the variable `hq`.

Comment: The text I am searching for (hq) is the range given(Y1:Ez1). then why find is not working. and other thing is it was working when I wrote this code, this error started after restart excel :-(.

Please help I worked hard for this & now its not working.

Comment: Hq is present in given range (y1:ez1). Why find can't search text. Pls explain.

Comment: I cannot tell what's going wrong. You will need to debug your code. All that I can say is that the value of `hq` is not found in `asheet.Range("$Y$1:$EZ$95")`. Make sure there are no additional spaces etc.